# Visual Studio break on Program.cs not on the line that throws the exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a C# console application. In `Program.cs`, I make calls to a variety of services. If one of those services throws an `Exception`, VS breaks in `Program.cs` and not on the line that is actually responsible for the error. The modal doesn't even indicate which line threw. I understand that you can still get the trace etc., but usually VS breaks on the responsible line which makes debugging far easier.

How can I get VS to break on the "external code"?

[image]

Comment: Please include a code snippet. This is most likely the result of you calling a method on a object that is null, and you have exception handling for guards in place. Most likely the [conditional access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?.` should help you get around this exception throw

Comment: I am not concerned with debugging the error, I am concerned with the fact that VS is not breaking on the line causing the error, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open **Exception Settings** from Debug > Windows > Exception Settings
2. Search your exception name.
3. Check the checkbox before your exception.
4. Uncheck **Enable Just My Code** in Debug > Options > Debugging > General